# Can't calculate offsetHeight from an element in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've got the following directive:

```
app.directive('myObject', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem){
      console.log(elem[0].offsetHeight);
    }
  };
});
```

Which basically is logging the `offsetHeight` of its target element, but it isn't working. I guess its because its calculating the height when the element hasn't got any content yet.

How can I resolve this issue without using a `timeout`?
Is there any built in solution for this problem?

[**Plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/3906CY0aUHw2YxOTkYLV?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `ng-repeat` renders lazily and the link function gets fired before that. You could resolve this issue by having `watcher` which will evaluate `elem[0].offsetHeight` value on each digest cycle. Therefore when `ng-repeat` completes it rendering it calls a digest cycle and due to change in `elem[0].offsetHeight` value it call its callback.

**Directive**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.directive('myObject', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem){
      var calculateHeight = scope.$watch(function(){
        return elem[0].offsetHeight;
      }, function(newVal, oldVal){
        //my awesome code here.
        console.log(newVal, oldVal);
        calculateHeight(); //de-registering watcher for performance reason
      })
    }
  };
});
```

[**Demo Here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/O1o4gg5PrX0I8Q71SX1X?p=preview)

---

Other alternative way you can do is, you can place other directive on ng-repeat element which will `$emit` an event once it completes with rendering & then we will have event listener inside directive, which will listen out that event and calculate height.

Comment: How can I make the watcher stop once it has logged one change?

Comment: @GEspinha look at the udpated answer please

Comment: Why are you rerunning the function inside the result?

Comment: @GEspinha that is de-register watcher.. basically it will remove watcher object from `$$watchers` object

Comment: I've noticed the oldVal isn't returning the `oldVal` its returning the current, is that right?

Comment: @GEspinha yes.. I think on first go oldVal & newVal would be same

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @GEspinha calling watcher function itself will tell angular to remove currently registerd watcher object, from `$$watchers`(all watchers are available here) object, do upvote please. :-) and cheers